# What's the purpose of flagging a question?

Tags: support

Recently I [flagged a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353766/how-to-get-the-value-for-data-target-in-this-xml),

[image]

as 'very low quality'. The flag was found helpful:

[image]

But still the question is neither deleted nor closed.

I also commented on it:

> Instead of concentrating on how to trick the quality filter by
>   repeating words so that your question is submitted, concentrate on
>   asking a good question as described in the help-center

As I can vote to close a question, where's the point of flagging it if doing this apparently doesn't have any effect at all?

To ask further, is the flag found helpful if only one other reviewer agreed with it? If so, is the flag also declined if only one other reviewer doesn't?

Until today (I didn't check this before) I thought flags would only be tagged helpful if they lead to a close/deletion.

Comment: It should have been closed as unclear what your asking (from what you've posted) , I wouldn't use lq flag on that. Low quality flag means it needs to be deleted right away, closing it was right choice to give op/other user chance to edit it.

Answer (score 8):

Your "very low quality" flag was marked as helpful the instant [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9370092) was approved. Edits on posts flagged as "very low quality" or "not an answer" mark those flags as helpful and remove flagged posts from flag queues.

This is intended to indicate that issues with the post have been solved by editing, but [sometimes this allows posts that should have been acted on to fall through the cracks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252854/edits-shouldnt-dismiss-not-an-answer-flags).